# "unknown" error in pom.xml when I upgrade from Spring 1.5.21 to 2.1.5

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Eclipse STS 3.9.7

The switch of Spring version creates other errors I'm able to solve, but not this one : first line of the pom.xml is tagged with "unkown" error.

Maven build (clean install) is running fine with no error no warnings.

What I've tried so far :

- Alt+F5 to update the project pom
- clean + build in eclipse
- close/reopen project
- close project/delete projet reimport project
- Close/reopen STS
- Delete project and all Eclipse metadata, then reimport as maven project.

When I switch back from 2.1.5 to 1.5.21, the error disappears instantly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking around, this is the solution :

It's an eclipse (or maven-jar-plugin) bug filed 2 days ago :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340

To solve the problem, downgrade maven-jar-plugin version from 3.1.2 to 3.1.1 through properties :

```
<properties>
    (...)
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```