# JPA spec Unidirectional OneToOne foreign PK raises error on repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

When trying to implement an example of the OneToOne association specified in the JPA 2.2 spec, I get a hibernate error at my repository, claiming it should be a composite key, although it's not.

I know there is some kind of solution with `@MapsId`, but wanted to get the jpa spec solution to work, if possible.

```java
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3659483897253805915L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    Parent() {} //jpa

    //getters/setters
}


@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6245572225910874612L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "parent_id" )
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;

    Child() {} //jpa

    //getters/setters
}
```

```java
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Parent> {}
```

Which raises the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'childRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.sample.onetoone.Child] does not define an IdClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$76/1992476840.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sample.onetoone.SpringOnetooneApplication.main(SpringOnetooneApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.sample.onetoone.Child] does not define an IdClass
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.AbstractIdentifiableType.getIdClassAttributes(AbstractIdentifiableType.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdMetadata.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:259) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:201) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:151) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport$$Lambda$387/121552774.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Changing the repository id to Long raises the same error.

```
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {}
```

---

JPA Spec 2.2, page 38:

https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf

---

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-onetoone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-onetoone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- WORKAROUND FOR POM.XML UNOWN ERROR IN LINE 1
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189383/unknown-error-in-pom-xml-when-i-upgrade-from-spring-1-5-21-to-2-1-5
         -->
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you try to change OneToOne to ManyToOne and see what happens?

Comment: I changed it to ManyToOne, but received the same error. Also, added full error stacktrace (had only CausedBy before).

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: How can the parent be the Id of the child? You need a separate Id property for the child.

Comment: Thats not true @Priyesh , in one to one relation foreign key can be also be primary key.

Comment: @Rohit added the pom.xml

Comment: Didn't know @Rohit. Thanks for that.

Comment: Will removing @Id annotation on Child.parent be a problem?

Comment: @Priyesh Each entity still requires an Id. We cannot omit it.

Comment: @Krabat Check example 2 at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html. I think that answers your question.

Comment: @Priyesh Sorry, not quite. As stated in my 2nd paragraph, I know there is solution by utilizing MapsId, but that's not what I am aiming for. Hibernate 5.3 implements the JPA 2.2 spec. In that spec I found that above code. Therefore I though Hibernate would support it somehow, but right now it does not seem to work. Thanks for looking into this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The @Id annotation serves to mark a primary key. For the child class, you are marking the parent as the primary key. Instead, try the following:

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6245572225910874612L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "parent_id" )
    private Parent parent;

    private String name;

    Child() {} //jpa

    //getters/setters
}
```

Comment: In the OneToOne relationship I am aiming for, the child won't use it's own id, but the id of the parent, which ensures tied coupled uniqueness.